# How do I change screen resolution in Fedora 16?

Tags: resolution, x-windows, xorg.conf, fedora-16

I have recently changed my OS to Fedora-16 64-bit, I know that my Screen resolution is `1920x1200`(From Previous OS on same Machine and other similar screens in my office). I have tried using `xrandr -q` Command to see the maximum Resolution available.

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024       0.0* 
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

My desired Resolution `1920x1200` is not listed in here. But I have tried using `xrandr -s 1920x1200` It has given following output `Size 1920x1200 not found in available modes`.

Can anybody help me in resolving this problems

Comment: What is the make and model of your monitor and graphics adapter?

Comment: Graphics: VESA: nv44 Board - q383-0. Dell Monitor for work station